# New to applescript

Tags: applescript

Essentially, what I am trying to accomplish is I want to cd into a specific directory containing all my lighthouse folders. I want to loop through each line of urls.txt and for every URL execute the npm lighthouse command and output the results into a CSV to analyze later.

```html
do shell script "cd /Users/user/Documents/Lighthouse\\"

set srcFile to "urls.txt"

set lns to paragraphs of (read file srcFile as «class utf8»)

repeat with ln in lns
    do shell script "npm lighthouse --throttling-method simulate --verbose --view --emulated-form-factor mobile --output-path "/Users/user/Documents/Lighthouse/LighthouseReports.csv" https://www.aphrodites.com/collections/bestsellers-home/products/tree-of-life-heart-edition-charm-bracelet-with-real-austrian-crystals"
end repeat
```

Some help would be fantastic, thank you!

Comment: Obvious problems: `do shell script` calls are not persistent so the first call to set cwd has no effect. AppleScript has no concept of cwd so you must use the full path, not a relative path, in your `read` command. Your repeat loop doesn’t actually use the resulting paragraphs; perhaps you meant `do shell script "…" & quoted form of contents of ln` instead of hardcoding the URL. You also need to backslash-escape the double quotes within the string literal. Honestly, you’d be easier just writing the whole thing as a shell script and not bother with AppleScript at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will probably get you a bit closer. At least, it's valid AppleScript for what I *think* you're trying to do (never having used lighthouse before). I'm assuming that you want that given URL in the `do shell script` to be the URL stored in each line of the file, right?

The `quoted form of` command makes sure that paths are properly quoted for unix, saving you some headaches. I've used the full path to npm, because `do shell script` doesn't import your interactive shell PATH variable and won't find that utility. if you ever want to know wether `do shell script` will be able to find a utility, run `do shell script "which utilityname"`; if the command errors out, use the full path.

```
set srcFolder to "/Users/user/Documents/Lighthouse/"

set srcFile to srcFolder & "urls.txt"
set outputPath to quoted form of (srcFolder & "LighthouseReports.csv")

set lns to paragraphs of (read file srcFile as «class utf8»)

repeat with ln in lns
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/npm lighthouse --throttling-method simulate --verbose --view --emulated-form-factor mobile --output-path " & outputPath & " " & quoted form of ln
end repeat
```